# Why assigning null in ternary operator fails: no implicit conversion between null and int?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

This fails with a `There is no implicit conversion between 'null' and 'int'`

```
long? myVar = Int64.Parse( myOtherVar) == 0 ? null : Int64.Parse( myOtherVar);
```

However, this succeeds:

```
if( Int64.Parse( myOtherVar) == 0)
    myVar = null;
else
    myVar = Int64.Parse( myOtherVar);
```

Is there a way to make the ternary operator succeed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The compiler ignores the left-hand side when figuring out the type of the right-hand side. So when it tries to deduce the type of

```
Int64.Parse(myOtherVar) == 0 ? null : Int64.Parse(myOtherVar)
```

it does so without paying any attention to the fact the left-hand side is a `long?`. To determine the type of the right-hand side it notes that

```
Int64.Parse(myOtherVar)
```

is a `long` and now tries to see if `null` is or can be implicitly converted to a `long`. Since it can not, you get the error message that you see.

From §7.14 of the C# specification:

> A conditional expression of the form `b ? x : y`....
>
> The second and third operands, `x` and `y`, of the `?:` operator control the type of the conditional expression.
>
> (1) If `x` has type `X` and `y` has type `Y` then
>
> a. If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from `X` to `Y`, but not from `Y` to `X`, then `Y` is the type of the conditional expression.
>
> b. If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from `Y` to `X`, but not from `X` to `Y`, then `X` is the type of the conditional expression.
>
> c. Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.
>
> (2) If only one of `x` and `y` has a type, and both `x` and `y`, of areimplicitly convertible to that type, then that is the type of the conditional expression.
>
> (3) Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

Note that we are in situation (2) where `x` is `null` and does not have a type and `y` is `Int64.Parse(myOtherVar)` and has type `long`. Note that `x` is not implicitly convertible to the type of `y`. Therefore both (1) and (2) fail above and we result in (3) which results in the compile-time error that inspired your question. **Note the implicit conclusion from the above that the left-hand side does not play a role in determining the type of right-hand side.**

To rectify this replace

```
Int64.Parse(myOtherVar)
```

with

```
(long?)Int64.Parse(myOtherVar)
```

Now, the reason why

```
myVar = null;
```

is okay where `myVar` is declared as `long?` is because the compiler knows there is an implicit conversion from `null` to `long?`.

Lastly, `Int64.Parse` will throw if `myOtherVar` can't be parsed to a `long`. Note that you are also performing the parse twice, which is unnecessary. A better pattern is

```
long value;
if(Int64.TryParse(myOtherVar, out value)) {
    myVar = value == 0 ? null : (long?)value;
}
else {
    // handle case where myOtherVar couldn't be parsed
}
```

Comment: Oddly, Int64.Parse(myOtherVar) == 0 ? (long?) null : Int64.Parse(myOtherVar); works.

Comment: That would really be nice if there was something similar to a "value" in an accessor, where you could create a temporary variable within the if statement.

Comment: @Dr. Zim: `Int64.Parse(myOtherVar) == 0 ? (long?) null : Int64.Parse(myOtherVar);` works because there is an implicit conversion from `long` to `long?`. So, `(long?)null` has type `long?` and `Int64.Parse(myOtherVar)` has type `long` which has an implicit conversion to `long?` and therefore the compiler types the expression as `long?`.

Answer (score 2):

Your operator usage is returning an `Int64`, not a `nullable` one, because of the last part of the ternary operator. It may work if you do instead:

```
long? myVar = Int64.Parse( myOtherVar) == 0 ? null :
   (long?)Int64.Parse( myOtherVar);
```

So that you are returning a `long?` instead, so the `null` doesn't need to be converted to `Int64`

Also, you are converting the value twice in your code, unnecessarily (once to test, and once to get the value). Your code might be better thus:

```
long? tempVar = Int64.Parse(myOtherVar);
long? myVar = tempVar==0? null : tempVar;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you meant to say:

```
  myVar = value == 0 ? null : (long?)value;
```

instead of

```
  myVar = value == 0 ? null : value;
```

I liked the usage of the 'out' variable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
long? myVar = (long?)myOtherVar == 0 ? null : (long?)myOtherVar;
```

..for those who like short answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Compiler tries to evaluate the expressions from left to right

```
long? myVar = Int64.Parse( myOtherVar) == 0 ? null : Int64.Parse( myOtherVar);
```

`int64.parse` method return a `long` value not a `nullable` long value. so there is no conversion between `null` and `Int64.Parse( myOtherVar);`
So, try this one

```
long? myVar = Int64.Parse(myOtherVar) == 0 ? (long?) null : Int64.Parse(myOtherVar);
```

OR
`long? myVar = Int64.Parse(myOtherVar) == 0 ? null : (long?) Int64.Parse(myOtherVar);`