# Doubts about the 'var' keyword and ternary operator ?:

Tags: c#, type-inference, ternary-operator, var

If `var` keyword is resolved at compile time, how does the following work?

```
class A {
}
class B : A {
}

int k = 1;
var x = (k < 0) ? new B() : new A();
```

**Edit:**
I finally understood that the problem is not about the `var` itself, but about the behaviour of the `?:` operator. For some reason, I thought that the following could be possible:

`object x = something ? 1 : ""`

and that's not possible at all :)

> Related question (about ternary operator):
>   [Why assigning null in ternary operator fails: no implicit conversion between null and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290203/simple-c-why-assigning-null-in-ternary-operator-fails-no-implicit-conversion-b)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result is of type `A`, because both of the variables are of type `A`, and at least one of them is *directly* of type `A` (not through some conversion).

The compiler takes a look at both parts of the ternary expression, and if one of them is a subtype of the other, the entire expression becomes the more general supertype.

However, *if neither is directly of the common type, then a compiler error occurs*, probably because it doesn't know how much to upcast for you (and it doesn't feel like finding out).

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the conditional operator.
>
> ```
> condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Comment: So, the static type will always be `A`? Any documentation where the behaviour of the `var` keyword in these contexts are explained?

Comment: @Oscar: Yes, if `A` is itself a common type (as is the case here). Not sure about the link but I'll let you know if I find it.

Comment: @Mehrdad Interesting... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Oscar: Sure. See the update (link) for the documentation, if you're interested.

Comment: Did you mean 'a compiler error occurs', I think you forgot *error* word. I'll not edit though, because I'm not sure. =)

Comment: @Miguel: Haha yes indeed I did, thanks for pointing it out! =)

Comment: @Mehrdad Thank you again. I was wrong about the behaviour of the `?:` operator :(. I always thought that the following could be valid: `object x = (k == 0) ? 1 : "Test"`, but as the documentation points out, that's not possible at all :)

Comment: @Oscar: I make that mistake a too when I'm coding, I think it's natural. :)

Comment: FYI - section 7.14 of the C# language specification

Answer (score 2):

The result is `A`. An easy way to confirm it is to place your mouse over the `var`.

Answer (score -7):

I haven't tested this degenerate case.  But I would bet either (1) compiler complains or (2) 'x' is of type 'A'.

Comment: Not useful answer at all. I'm asking how this work, what is the compiler doing, and not just what happens. Of course, I can open Visual Studio and test it. In fact, (1) isn't