# Ternary Operator in C#

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, ternary-operator

Can anyone please explain to me what happens behind the scenes when you use ternary operator?
does this line of code:

```
string str = 1 == 1 ? "abc" : "def";
```

is generated as a simple if / else statement?
Consider the following:

```
class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}

class C : A
{
}
```

Now using ternary expression as follows:

```
A a1 = 1 == 1 ? new B() : new C();
```

this doesn't even compile with this error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'ConsoleApp1.B' and 'ConsoleApp2.C'

Can anyone shed light on this one?

Comment: Take a look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4290218/26396

Comment: Note: this isn't really about the CLR, and although its *a* ternary operator (and the only one, as it happens) the operator's *name* is the conditional operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional operator will effectively use the type of the first expression for the second according to whether there is a conversion - and doesn't take into account bases (otherwise it would just always go to `object` allowing this: `? "hello" : 10`).

In this case, the compiler is correct - there is no conversion between the two types.  Add a cast, however on the first one - and it'll compile - `(A)new B()`.

Answer (score 8):

The type of the conditional operator expression is required to be *either* the type of the second operand *or* the type of the third operand. So one of those must be convertible to the other.

In your case, they're not convertible to each other - but both convertible to a third type (A). That isn't considered by the compiler, but you can force it:

```
A a1 = 1 == 1 ? new B() : (A) new C();
```

or

```
A a1 = 1 == 1 ? (A) new B() : new C();
```

See section 7.14 of the C# 4 spec for more details.

Answer (score 3):

An extract from [msdn ?Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> If condition is true, first expression is evaluated and becomes the result; 
>   if false, the   second expression is evaluated and becomes the result. 
>   Only one of two expressions is ever  evaluated.

Its pretty explicit.

And your error is pretty explicit too, you are trying to assign a B to a C ... But no cast is available, so error ... Pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

> Its pretty explicit.
>
> And your error is pretty explicit too, you are trying to assign a B to
>   a C ... But no cast is available, so error ... Pretty simple

Not relevant at all.

B and C derives from A.

The expression is:

A a1 = 1 == 1 ? new B() : new C();

Both expressions return type that derives from A

Just the compiler looks at the expressions of the ?: operator, and don't care what is the type of variable a1 (left side of the expression)...
The reason for such implementation is very interesting...